# Repeating background banner in Android application

Tags: android, background, repeat

I have an image that is 100px by 100px and would like the image to keep its ratio but tile across the the screen to create a sort of banner. Is this possible? I have searched google and have only found examples which fill the whole screen with the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an xml drawable.  In your drawable folder create a new xml file, say, background.xml.   Then put this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
            <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/backgroundTile"
                android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then just set that as the background of your `View`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast response. Your suggestion worked great, however the image seems to be more grainy than I expected. Could it be because I am viewing the app on an emulator?

Comment: Could be.  The emulator screen is scaled up for the smaller screens.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:tileMode="repeat"`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#attr_android:tileMode